# Iterator, set, if-else tags of Struts2(Getting the value of s:radio and applying if-else )

Tags: struts2, iterator

I have a jsp page in which I have two radio buttons and a select tag. Now, if the first radio button is clicked than I want to make that select tag disable **but I am fail to do this** , I have tried using "disabled" property. Following is the code.
Jsp Page

```
<table align="center">
<s:iterator value="FirstObjectList" status="AuthorTypeStatus">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:radio name="radio_SelectedValue" list="{ObjectName}" listKey="ObjectKey" listValue="ObjectName" value="DefaultObject"/>                                  
        </td>
    </tr>           
</s:iterator>
<s:if test="%{#radio_SelectedValue == 'ObjectName1'}">
    <s:set name="isSelectDisabled" value="false"/>              
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:set name="isSelectDisabled" value="True"/>
</s:else>

<tr >
    <td colspan="2">
        Select Parent Discover Lab
    </td>           
</tr>       
<tr>        
    <td>
        <s:select name="select_SelectedValue" headerKey="DefaultObject" headerValue="ParentObject" list="ObjectList" listKey="ObjectListKey" listValue="ObjectListValue" disabled="%{isSelectDiabled}">
            <s:iterator value="ObjectList">
            </s:iterator>
        </s:select>

        <s:submit value="Continue">
        </s:submit>                         
    </td>

</tr>
```

All the getter and setter methods are fixed..is this possible without javascript?

Comment: No you must use javascript (or a JS framework like jQuery) for this type of problem.  Only post the generated html not the jsp, tag the question with jQuery and or javascript and you'll get a lot of good answers.

Comment: @Quaternion: Thanks for your time and consideration. I was trying to know that if I we can do it the other way(except JQuery). Because logically if we think than it is possible. Correct me If I am wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: The JSP is on the server.  If there is no java script then what you send is what the client gets. There will be no dynamic behavior it is just as if you sent a picture. With java script you are sending a program, if a client clicks on a drop down you can now describe with JS how other parts of the page are to behave.

Comment: There are web frame works that build in dynamic functionality into tags (the tags write the JS on the client for us). As a matter of fact Struts2 has a collection of ajax tags, however they have been deprecated and for good reason.  Simply such tags are too brittle, that is they will serve their intended purpose but more often than not we need something just a little different. Then you might as well write the JS from scratch. Imagine trying to use a bunch of xml tags to write Java, that doesn't make must sense and no more so for JS.  The conclusion, use JS directly. jQuery makes it even fun.

Comment: @Quaternion: Thank you so much for such a nice explaination, previously I was thinking to do something different and go against the culture..but thanks to you, I learnt the main reason behind using JQuery etc. Happy to be dumb as I am able to learn lot of things from you guys... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your code block, but I think I understand what you're aiming for. Something like this should work

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:radio name="radio_SelectedValue" list="%{radioList}" listKey="ObjectKey" listValue="ObjectName" value="DefaultObject"/>                                  
        </td>
    </tr>

    <s:if test="%{radio_SelectedValue.equals('myChosenValueFromTheList')}">
             <s:select name="select_SelectedValue" headerKey="-1" headerValue=" " list="ObjectList" listKey="ObjectList.Key" listValue="ObjectList.Value" />       
    </s:if><s:else>
        <s:select name="select_SelectedValue" headerKey="-1" headerValue=" " list="ObjectList" listKey="ObjectList.Key" listValue="ObjectList.Value" disabled="disabled" />   
    </s:else>
```

I'm not sure what you're doing with the iterators with these tags, they handle the list propagation themselves. Simply tell the tag what list to use and struts will populate the tags appropriately. You can then do a conditional based on the value of the radio when the page renders and perform magic on the select tag as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for your time and consideration. I have used iterator (in case of Radio Buttons) to display Radio Button in different lines and if I am not using the iterator than the Radio Buttons are displayed in the same line. And with regard to the "<s:select/>" the solution you gave is not working, only the else condition is executed. :)

Comment: If statements default to false, which means the property is not being returned as expected. In this case I generally plug my value in a s:property tag to see what is being pushed into the value stack. So just take the value you're checking against and do a s:property value='myValue' and see what is being returned.

Comment: I think Quaternion is correct. We are taking the wrong path to achieve the target, JQuery is the better option. By the way thanks for your time and consideration if you find anything new and if you have got any example regarding my question than please share it..thanks :) happy coding.